# Mysql Event to run on every sunday every 1 hour

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks, mysql-event

I'm to new to mysql event scheduling and want to schedule a task which should run on every sunday internal of 1 hour.

Can any one help with this ?

```
CREATE EVENT event_forEverysundayeveryhour
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Week
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO Begin

End;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT event_forEverysundayeveryhour
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR -- Starts on the next Sunday at 1 AM
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
  -- Your event logic here
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank for the answer Hasan raza but this will going to run only for single week. I want scheduler to run every week on sunday for every hour

Comment: try this one as per your requirements